# Проблема с модальными окнами php и запросами в бд

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, modal

Я создал страничку, которая забирает из базы данных некие данные о товаре и отображает ввиде таблицы и есть кнопка на модальное окно, в котором дублируются некоторые дыне что бы с дуру не то не отредактировал, с выводом информации все Ок, а вот взять с модального окна и записать в БД Боль и Печаль. Проблема еще в том что колличество надо внести в отдельную таблице, а закупочную цену в другу.

Еще вопрос: нужно ли сделать связь между таблицей товара и таблицей информации о закупе?

И там момент: количество нужно записать в в таблицу товара и в закуп.

[image: Скриншот]

[image: Скриншот]

[image: Скриншот]

```
    <?php session_start(); if (isset($_SESSION['users_id']) && isset($_SESSION['users_name'])) { ?>

<?php include("./core/nav/header.php"); ?>

<?php include "./core/database/db_conn.php"; ?>

<div class="table-responsive p-3 mt-3">
    <table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" style="width:100%">
        
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Артикул</th>
                <th>Наименование</th>
                <th>Категория</th>
                <th>Поставщик</th>
                <th><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-pencil-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z"/>
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z"/>
</svg></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
                
        <tbody>
            <?php
                $select_stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT @a:= @a+1 as `num`, `product`.* FROM `product` JOIN (SELECT @a:= 0 FROM DUAL) "); 
                $select_stmt->execute();
                while($row=$select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
            ?>

                <tr>
                    <td ><?php echo $row['num']; ?></td>
                    <td ><?php echo $row['product_article']; ?></td>
                    <td ><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></td>
                    <td ><?php echo $row['product_category']; ?></td>
                    <td ><?php echo $row['product_suppliers']; ?></td>

                                                
                    <td>
                    <!-- Кнопка-триггер модального окна -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-pencil-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z"/>
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z"/>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                     <!-- Конец кнопки-триггера модального окна -->
</td>

                
                </tr>
            <?php
                }
т           ?>
        </tbody>
        
    </table>
</div>


<!-- -->

<!-- Модальное окно -->
<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">Заголовок модального окна</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Закрыть"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <!-- тело модального окна -->
<тdiv class="container mt-4">

  тттт      <div class="row g-3 mt-4 align-items-center">
                            
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label class="col-form-label">Артикул :</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-1">

                            <?php 
                                    $sql    = "SELECT `product_article` FROM product;";
                                    $stmt   = $conn->prepare($sql); 
                                    $stmt->execute();
                                    $users  = $stmt->fetchAll();
                                    ?>
                    
                                    <?php foreach($users as $user): ?> 
                                    <select id="product_article" name="product_article" >
                                        <option value="<?= $user['product_article']; ?>"><?= $user['product_article']; ?></option> 
                                    </select>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>        
                            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row g-3 mt-4 align-items-center">
                            
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label class="col-form-label">Наименование :</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-1">

                            <?php 
                                    $sql    = "SELECT `product_name` FROM product;";
                                    $stmt   = $conn->prepare($sql); 
                                    $stmt->execute();
                                    $users  = $stmt->fetchAll();
                                    ?>
                    
                                    <?php foreach($users as $user): ?> 
                                    <select id="product_name" name="product_name" >
                                        <option value="<?= $user['product_name']; ?>"><?= $user['product_name']; ?></option> 
                                    </select>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>        
                            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row g-3 mt-4 align-items-center">
                            
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label class="col-form-label">Наименование :</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-1">

                            <?php 
                                    $sql    = "SELECT `product_suppliers` FROM product;";
                                    $stmt   = $conn->prepare($sql); 
                                    $stmt->execute();
                                    $users  = $stmt->fetchAll();
                                    ?>
                    
                                    <?php foreach($users as $user): ?> 
                                    <select id="product_suppliers" name="product_suppliers" >
                                        <option value="<?= $user['product_suppliers']; ?>"><?= $user['product_suppliers']; ?></option> 
                                    </select>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>        
                            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row g-3 mt-4 align-items-center">
                        
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label class="col-form-label">Колличество :</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input type="text" name="count" class="form-control" placeholder="Например : 50 мл" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-1">
<!-- нужно написать запрос что бы он плюсовал к общему количеству товара -->
                        <?php 
                                $sql    = "SELECT `product_quantity` FROM product;";
                                $stmt   = $conn->prepare($sql); 
                                $stmt->execute();
                                $users  = $stmt->fetchAll();
                                ?>
 <!-- конец то чего надо написать запрос что бы он плюсовал к общему количеству товара -->      
                        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row g-3 mt-4 align-items-center">
                        
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label class="col-form-label">Закупочная цена :</label>
                        </div>
<!-- нужно написать запрос что бы он записывал в отдельную таблице инфу по закупу об этом товаре время дата объем, цена и по какому курсу было куплено -->
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" placeholder="Например : 80 $" required>
                        </div>
<!-- конец то чего надо написать запрос что бы он записал в отдельной таблице инфу по закупу об этом товаре--> 
                        <div class="col-md-1">

                        <?php 
                                $sql    = "SELECT `actuality` FROM exchange_rates;";
                                $stmt   = $conn->prepare($sql); 
                                $stmt->execute();
                                $users  = $stmt->fetchAll();
                                ?>
                   
                                <?php foreach($users as $user): ?> 
                                <select id="actuality" name="actuality" >
                                    <option value="<?= $user['actuality']; ?>"><?= $user['actuality']; ?></option> 
                                </select>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>        
                        </div>
        </div>


</div>
        <!-- конец теля модально окна-->

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Понял</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- -->


<?php  include("./core/nav/footer.php"); ?>
<?php }else {
    header("Location: 404.php");
    exit;
} ?>
```

Comment: Кошмар какой то. Не хотите начать работать с каким ни будь фреймворком, Laravel к примеру?

Comment: нет не хочу, хочу сначало в php приуспеть и толко после когда все поиму буду смотреть на фреимворки, мои препод по психологии говорил : *не изучив фундаментальное, что станешь недо специалистом, который на первом повороте улетит в кувейт*

Comment: потому если можете дать полезные настовления, я весь внимании

Comment: В Кувейт?  Ахахаха

Comment: ну так это и есть полезное наставление, потому что тот код, который приведен выше, это пчелы, мед, г..о и каша

Comment: скажем так, я отночсительно недавно начал учить php не можете подсказать, прошу лишним говном коменты не засорять

Comment: @zortwarut Комментарии выше отображают реальную картину по коду.. это каша) для начала изучите какой-то шаблонизатор, изучите паттерн MVC хотяб его) Ларавел вас научит разделять код на логические составляющие.. там тот же php) что касается ответа на конкретный вопрос - ваш код даже не охота изучать(

Comment: Присоединяюсь к комментарию выше. Вам стоит понять, что плохо совмещать в одном коде (файле) получение и отображение данных. https://elisdn.ru/blog/113/psr7-framework-http - советую этот ресурс. Здесь подробно объясняется почему, зачем и как. 7 видео вас научат пониманию общей картины +- современного php

Comment: Советчики... Хоть бы для начала объяснили, что запросы все должны идти до вывода, а потом уже ларку свою втюхивали...

Comment: Тема закрыта, все решилось банальным CRUD, все идельно отображается. меняется, заливается.....

Comment: Патерны им подавай, Вы уважаемые когда пишите хотя бы на минутку внимательно почитайте что человек только начал учить пхп, иди говорит фреивокром головои об стену убеися, а если мне потом на работу, и там не ларавел будет, аЮи или еще чего?????